# Merge two datatables which have the same columns but one both have some null cells

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

I have two datatables, say d1 and d2, whose columns are say A, B, C, D.

I am saving data into d1 and only the cells corresponding to column A, B are filled similarly with d2 only cells corresponding to C, D are filled. I want to make a single datatable which will be having data of both d1 and d2. i.e it will be having the data corresponding to column A, B from d1 and column C, D from d2.
I am filling the data into both d1 and d2 from different viewmodels so these are kinda segregated.

My approach:

I fetched one of datatable, say d1, to my target save source, now I am just putting the values corresponding to column C, D from d2 into my target save source, but it's not working.

Code:

```
DataTable employeeDataTable;
DataTable personalDataTable;
DataTable educationDataTable;

public DataTable GetPersonalDetails(DataTable dataTable1)
{
    personalDataTable   = dataTable1;      
}

public void  EducationDetails(DataTable dataTable)
{
    educationDataTable   = dataTable;
    employeeDataTable = personalDataTable.Copy();
    employeeDataTable.Rows[0]["Graduation"] = educationDataTable.Rows[0]["Graduation"];
    employeeDataTable.Rows[0]["PostGraduation"] = educationDataTable.Rows[0]["PostGraduation"];

    return employeeDataTable;
}
```

Comment: How do you know which C and D values from d2 correspond to A and B values of some row in d1?

Comment: "Graduation" / "PostGraduation" are say column C,D . I am beginner to datatables that's why seeking help .

Comment: I don't understand you. What is relation between A,B and C,D?

Comment: there is no relation its just like value of cells for A,B are bring fetched from some other source keeping value of C,D empty in it , similarly for C,D . I want to merge the both datatables .

Comment: I don't understand you. Which row(s) of d1 correspond to first row of d2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example you are setting only the values on Row[0]. Perhaps you're only doing that as a test, but to do all rows you need to loop with index i instead of zero, and loop for each row of the data table.

```
int numRows = employeeDataTable.Rows.Count;

for(int i = 0; i < numRows; ++i)
{
     employeeDataTable.Rows[i]["Graduation"] = educationDataTable.Rows[i]["Graduation"];
     employeeDataTable.Rows[i]["PostGraduation"] = educationDataTable.Rows[i]["PostGraduation"];     
}
```